# variable len string

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i have a packet struct which have a variable len for a string example:

```
BYTE StringLen;
String MyString; //String is not a real type, just trying to represent an string of unknown size
```

My question is how i can make the implementation of this packet inside an struct without knowing the size of members (in this case strings). Here is an example of how i want it to "look like"

```
void ProcessPacket (PacketStruct* packet)
{
     pointer = &packet.MyString;
}
```

I think its not possible to make since the compiler doesn't know the size of the string until run time. So how can make it look high level and comprehensible?.

The reason i need structs its for document every packet without the user actually have to look any of the functions that analyze the packet.

So i can resume the question to: **is there a way to declare an struct of undefined size members or something close as a struct?**

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: This question is unclear: I have no idea what you’re asking here.

Comment: Its simple how can i make an structure or class wich have a variable len string... and reference its members on a comprehensible method.

Comment: Just an example, i want to know if there is a method for compiler to understand that a variable size member is on that position.

Comment: what more do you want? its just a simple question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a shell class that just interprets the packet data.

```
struct StringPacket {
    char *data_;
    StringPacket (char *data) : data_(data) {}
    unsigned char len () const { return *data_; }
    std::string str () const { return std::string(data_+1, len());
};
```

As mentioned in comments, you wanted a way to treat a variable-sized packet like a `struct`. The old C way to do that was to create a `struct` that looked like this:

```
struct StringPacketC {
    unsigned char len_;
    char str_[1]; /* Modern C allows char str_[]; but C++ doesn't */
};
```

And then, cast the data (remember, this is C code):

```
struct StringPacketC *strpack = (struct StringPacketC *)packet;
```

But, you are entering undefined behavior, since to access the full range of data in `strpack`, you would have to read beyond the `1` byte array boundary defined in the `struct`. But, this is a commonly used technique in C.

But, in C++, you don't have to resort to such a hack, because you can define accessor methods to treat the variable length data appropriately.

Comment: Isn't there any way to represent the packet into a struct? Assuming the packet might have members of undefined size?. The reason i want to use structs its caused i need to document a large portion of packets in the source code without the user actually look the implementation of it.

Comment: @user1175832: The old C style way was to declare the last parameter of a `struct` with a small char array (e.g. 1). But, you don't get any type safety with that approach, so I don't know why you would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the string into a high-level std::string (at least, if my guess that `String` is a typedef for `const char*` is correct):

```
void ProcessPacket( const PacketStruct& packet )
{
  std::string highLevelString( packet.MyString,
                               static_cast< size_t >( packet.StringLen ) );
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple variant according to your posting would be:

```
struct PacketStruct {
   std::string MyString;
   size_t length () const { return MyString.length(); }
   const char* operator & () const { return MyString.c_str(); }
};
```

This can be used (almost) as you desired above:

```
 void ProcessPacket (const PacketStruct& packet)
{
  const char * pointer = &packet;
  size_t length = packet.length();
  std::cout << pointer << '\t' << length << std::endl;
}
```

and should be invoked like:

```
 int main()
{
 PacketStruct p;
 p.MyString ="Hello";
 ProcessPacket(p);
}
```